# Allowing my python code to read data from DB2 on openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

I have a python code that needs to read data from a restricted DB2. I do know about secrets in build configs of Openshift,however I did not get any which can be useful like this. Also what should be the appropriate syntax in my code to read from that Secret. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of options of using secrets or configMaps in DeploymentConfig for your scenario:

- Propagate data through environment variables
- Mount secret as a volume

There're both [examples](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/secrets.html#secrets-in-volumes-and-env-vars)

I suggest to propagate password through *secretKeyRef* environment variable:

```
env:
  - name: DB2_PASSWORD
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: bd2-password
        key: password
```

To create secret:

```
oc create secret generic db2-password --from-literal=password=Qwerty123
```